# How can I confirm that my book title isn't already taken?

Tags: publishing, titles

I am writing a book that I plan to self-publish through Amazon's self-publishing service.

My book is non-fiction. Searching Amazon.com, I could not find any other book with my title, yet it seems a fairly generic title, and I'm very surprised it isn't taken yet.

Is there a larger database somewhere of all books in the ISBN that I can search to confirm that my book's title is in fact original?

Comment: Look it up on google. If it’s not there it’s fine.

Comment: [ISBN Search](https://isbnsearch.org/)

Comment: There's no rule against having the same title as another book, although it can be desirable to stand out and be unique. For instance there are dozens of books called *My Story* by writers from Uri Gellar to Ronald Kray.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Google Books [advanced search](https://books.google.com/advanced_book_search) to find book titles that contain specific words (or search in Google Books for a phrase with `intitle:"search terms"`). There are a lot of books that Google has indexed so you may get some obscure hits.

That being said, it helps to know that [titles can’t be copyrighted](https://www.writersdigest.com/copyrights/can-you-copyright-a-title), and can only be trademarked if distinctive, so the title being “taken” might not be an issue, at least legally.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search can go a long way, and [ISBN Search](https://isbnsearch.org/) mentioned by Alexander may be useful as well. Even if you do happen to share a title with someone else, I don't believe it is the end of the world, just change it a bit or even go on with your title. You said the title is fairly generic, I don't think it's likely you'd get sued over sharing a common title.